# How can I have a textarea popup when the user clicks a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, textarea

I've tried [PopBox](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/popBox) to have a textarea pop up, but the functionality of PopBox seems to be incompatible with the game system. (For example, I know for a fact that `alert();` and `prompt();` works in the html page testing, but does not happen at all in the actual game)

Currently the game has [this confirm box](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/) system implemented. Is there a way to add a textarea to this?

If not, is there any other Jquery/JS tricks/plugins that will allow a textarea box to pop up when a button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this plugin

[**jAlert**](http://flwebsites.biz/jAlert/)

very easy and clean to use, you can do whatever you want.

its easy to change the input by a textarea

in **`jquery.alerts.js`** file, search for `'prompt'` case, and change the `input` by `textarea`.

i made this for me and have been working so far.

Comment: Your link is now broken.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert but I think this is possible:

```
<div id="textAreaDiv" style="visibility:hidden;"><textarea></textarea></div>

<input type="button" onClick="showTextArea()">
<input type="button" onClick="hideTextArea()">

<script>
function showTextArea() {
document.getElementById('textAreaDiv').style.visibility="visible";
}

function hideTextArea() {
document.getElementById('textAreaDiv').style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
```

OR...

To toggle the DIV with one button, you could do this:

```
<script>
function showHideTextarea() {
if (document.getElementById('textAreaDiv').style.visibility="hidden")
{
document.getElementById('textAreaDiv').style.visibility="visible";
}
else
{
document.getElementById('textAreaDiv').style.visibility="hidden";
}
}
</script>
```

And this doesn't need the JQuery library to use.

Hope it helps...

Comment: I think this would show a textarea that was hidden on the page, but not pop it into its own box. Thank you for your efforts though!

Comment: I think that all depends on how you apply CSS to this answer. The DIV could pop up if the right CSS was applied. Please clarify what you mean and I may still be able to help you

Comment: I found that the JAlert plugin works, but again, thank you for your time. It's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can try jquery dialog http://jqueryui.it/demos/dialog.

This pops open an overlay and a dialog. You can customize this display and interaction to your hearts desire.

Comment: Link seems broken

Answer (score 0):

You can have a  on the page, which inserts a textarea box when the button is clicked, something like this...

In original HTML page, stick a blank area, maybe reserving space like so

```
<div id="Input_Area">
<br>
<br>
</div>
```

Then, put an onClick event on your button which replaces the innerHTML with your textarea (or create a function that does it, and call it with your onClick event).